# Exclude some files when extracting with tar

Tags: tar

I need to extract huge file (`.tgz`) where I have thousands of unnecessary sessions located in folder `/var/s3/tmp`, so I want to exclude that directory while I'm extracting that file.

I have tried something like `--exclude=/var/s3/tmp`, but it didn't work.

Comment: What do those files look like in the tarball? e.g. `tar tvzf foo.tgz | fgrep s3/tmp`

Comment: Like this: `s3/tmp/sess_8bhdakn7gs3em4174...`

Comment: So shouldn't you use `--exclude=s3/tmp` instead?